# text wrapping on a texture applied to a 3D model

Tags: graphics, textures, graphics-programming

How would I create and implement a texture of text that wraps around a 3D model? The texture will just be white and you should be able to add text to it, but I need to create this so that when the texture is wrapped around a model of a person, the person is then composed of lines of text and the lines should not be distorted.

In my head the way I would do it is to put the flattened texture in a file, and draw text on to it. Is this the best way? are there any issues that I'm unaware of that I might come across?

Comment: A render target is probably what you are looking for. What engine are you using?

Comment: It might help to realize that this problem has little to do specifically with text.

Comment: well it might indeed help, yes. So can you?

Comment: "I have zero experience with textures" Then you should get experience with textures before trying to do something so specific. There's plenty of information online about texture mapping.

Comment: I'll edit the question.......

Comment: @TJMonk15 DirectX10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a link](http://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut22.html)
This is part of a DX10 tutorial series, but this one covers rendering to a texture. I think you can abstract it and render text to it very easily. (Never tried to render text in DX before)